# Scope to get true or false if user subscribed to channel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have three tables:

**users** (id, name)

**channel** (id, name)

**subscription** (user_id, channel_id)

Now I try to implement a scope for the Channel-Model. To this scope I pass the ID of an user.

As an output I want to get something like this:

**Columns:** Channel ID - Channel Name - Subscribed (True/False)

One approach was something like this:

```
$query->selectSub(function($q) use ($userId) {
  $q->select(DB::raw('1'));
}, 'subscribed');
```

Comment: Ok... What have you tried then, what's failing? Where's the code?

Comment: If you want to see some code: public function scopeWithSubscribed($query, $userId) {}

Comment: I'd suggest adding this into the question rather than the comment section.

Comment: Please check question, I did.

Answer (score 1):

The intended purpose of a scope is adding constraints to a query, not adding columns.
So, for example, only fetch active channels.

You could change your app to work with separate queries:

```
$userChannels = User::find($userId)->channels;
$channels = Channel::all();
foreach($channels as $channel) {
    $channel->subscribed = $userChannels->contains($channel);
}
```

This requires a `BelongsToMany` relationship `User` → `Channel`:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function channels() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Channel:class, 'subscription');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jonas. But I don't want to check, if the channel is subscribed by the user via Laravel. This should just passed to the json-response because I'm implementing an API here. Work-around would be to do a ->with() and only join the subscriptions-entry where the user-id equals the requested user-id. So in the response is an array of subscription-entries (always one). But just getting true or false would be better...

Comment: Ok, solve it with a selectSub(). You said, that scopes are not a good way to solve this. Do you have a tip for me, where to put such a stuff ? Thank you!

Comment: Your response is an array of all channels and each should have a boolean `subscribed` value for the requested user?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Its working well now with the scope, but maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. But that's not really an elegant solution either... The only difference to your solution could be performance. For large tables multiple simple queries might be faster than one complex query with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this code:

```
$query->selectSub(function($q) use ($userId) {
  $q->from('subscriptions');
  $q->whereRaw('subscriptions.spot_id = channels.id');
  $q->select(DB::raw('IF(COUNT(1) > 0, true, false)'));
}, 'subscribed');
```

At the moment I put this stuff to a scope of the Channel-model. Is there a better place?